# How can I run python file with arguments in Java code

Tags: python, java

I'm trying run a Python file with argument in Java code. When I run the file in Mac Os terminal, it works perfectly, but when I tried in Java code, it doesn't work.

In terminal I type this:

```
python import.py 10477 > out.txt
```

That command generates a out.txt correctly, but it doesn't work in my Java code. I tried with this:

```
String path = "/Users/Atlas/Desktop/Job/Python";
String textValue = textFixVersion.getText(); # Get value from a TextBox

if(releaseRadio.isSelected()) { # Radio Button

     String terminal = "python import.py " + textValue + " > out.txt";

     try {
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(terminal,null,new File(path));
     }
     catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Atlass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

This code is the same when I execute Jar files within my Java code and it working perfectly. I'm working with Python 3.9.10.

Comment: It doesn't work because `>` is functionality of your shell, and the way `runtime.exec` works does not involve your shell. You either need to execute without the redirect and read the default output of your process and write it to a file yourself, or you need to call exec in a way that invokes your shell to perform the redirect for you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right, I solved with this `exec(new String[]{"bash","-c",terminal},null,new File(path))`. Thank you for your support.